# Rolagem continua da página após div com rolagem interna

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5

No meio da página tenho uma div com uma rolagem interna, quando rolo a página e chego até esta div ao usar a roda do mouse fico preso nela, quando a div acaba a rolagem não continua para o restante da página, existe uma forma de fazer com que a rolagem seja continua?

Como exemplo tem a página de vídeos do globo play: https://globoplay.globo.com/v/5136913/

Comment: É bom ter o código pra gente poder olhar melhor.

Comment: Porque você não coloca um "scroll" interno, em css bem pequeno?

Comment: Veja que no exemplo que você deu, é preciso passar o mouse em cima do box, para que ele faça o scroll interno. Ele deve ter usando um "onmouseup". e "onmouseout" para entrar/sair do evento. Isso não tem a ver com o layout.

Comment: Meu layout é maior que a altura do box, porém quando rolo o conteúdo dentro do box usando a roda do mouse e este conteúdo chega ao fim não consigo rolar o restante da página, a rolagem fica presa a este box.

Comment: algo parecido com isso: `<div onmouseover="this.style.overflow='auto';document.body.style.overflow='hidden';" onmouseout="this.style.overflow='hidden';document.body.style.overflow='auto'"></div>
`

Comment: Resolvi o problema, era questão de ambiente, no interno não estava funcionando, obrigado pela ajuda!